# Don't see texture in UDK from Blender object

Tags: textures, blender, unreal-development-kit

I am starting with UDK by creating a map of my home. I am creating the furniture in Blender, then export it to `.fbx` and finally import it in UDK to use it. The problem is that I can't achieve to see the texture I created with Blender in UDK. In UDK I see a plain default texture instead the one I created in Blender. I am following this tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4J-T0mCSyl8).

Could you help me to get the texture in UDK?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. When you export Blender object to import it in UDK you have to keep in mind the follow:

1º The texture image can't be .jpg (.png is ok)

2º The texture image must be square

Answer (score 1):

You can't put textures in fbx files. Import the tetures with UDK's content browser, create a material using your texture for the diffuse channel and apply this material to your mesh in the content browser.

[An elaborate tutorial how to do this.](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/MaterialsTutorial.html)

Comment: As far as I know you can put UV coordinates, vertex colors and material groups in a fbx. Never heard of a way to put a texture file in a fbx. Neither have I stumpled upon a way to access a texture other than a texture file from a material/shader. Have you painted the meshes inside Blender? Then you are looking for a material/shader that uses the vertex color for diffuse.